# How to remove the header at the top of the Razer Merchant Service page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

I would like to remove the header at the top of the Razer Merchant Service page in Flutter. Is it any solution to remove it?

this is the code segment:

```
Padding(
               padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, right: 12.0, left: 12.0),
                           child: ElevatedButton(
                               style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                 minimumSize: Size(double.infinity, 50),
                                 primary: Colors.amberAccent,
                                 shadowColor: Colors.yellowAccent,),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      var paymentDetails = {
                                        'mp_app_name': '',   
                                        'mp_username': '',
                                        'mp_password': '',
                                        'mp_merchant_ID': '',
                                        'mp_verification_key': '',
                                        'mp_amount' : '',
                                        'mp_order_ID': '',   
                                        'mp_currency': '',
                                        'mp_country': '',
                                        'mp_bill_name': ',
                                        'mp_bill_email': '',
                                        'mp_bill_mobile': '',
                                        'mp_bill_description' : 'Payment',
                                        'mp_sandbox' : false,
                                        'mp_dev_mode' : false,
                                      };
                                      String result = await molpay.startMolpay(paymentDetails);
                                      print("Result" + result);
                                    },
                                    child: Text("Continue", style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 16,)))
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remove all the `appBar` property from your `Scaffold` widget.

So, change this code:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar:AppBar(title: Text('flutter')), //*** remove appBar properety ***
    body: BodyWidget()
)
```

into this code:

```
Scaffold(
    //appBar:AppBar(title: Text('flutter')),
    body: BodyWidget()
)
```

More info [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html)

Comment: String result = await molpay.startMolpay(paymentDetails);

But, I did not set the appBar.
In my case, the interface straight away proceeds to the Razer page when a button is clicked.
If like this situation, how can I find the appBar in the Razer page because the page is generated automatically with the plugin.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thought you built it in flutter. Sorry for that. Good luck to you ;0)

Comment: is it any solution that can be set to remove that one?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: I already edited and updated the code.